# SharePoint 2010 "unhandled win32 exception occurred in W3WP.EXE"

Tags: c#, debugging, sharepoint-2010

I am getting an win32 exception that I need help debugging.  I have a SharePoint page that has a custom Web Part that when I browse to that page, I get the following message:

```
In w3wp.dmp the assembly instruction at ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+62 in 
C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an unknown
exception (0xc0000374) on thread 43

Unhandled exception at 0xHEX in w3wp.exe: 0xc0000374: 
A heap has been corrupted
```

I don't really know where to begin debugging this issue and searching the internet has yielded very little results.

I have saved the DMP file and I've loaded it into the Debug Diagnostic Tool for analysis. I don't know what parts are most important, so if someone could tell me which sections I should post, I will post them.

### Where I think the problem is:

I have narrowed down the location of where the problem *might* be.  If I don't call these methods, I don't get the error.  Is there something wrong with the way I'm accessing the TermStore?

```
    private void GetTerms()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(PhaseListUrl.Value))
        {
            var session = new TaxonomySession(site);
            if (session.TermStores == null || session.TermStores.Count == 0) return;

            OfficeDropdown.Items.Clear();
            OfficeDropdown.Items.Add("");

            var termStore = session
                .TermStores
                .FirstOrDefault(ts => ts.Groups.Any(g => g.Name == TaxonomyName.Value));
            try
            {
                var group = termStore.Groups[TaxonomyName.Value];
                foreach (var ts in group.TermSets)
                {
                    if (!ts.IsAvailableForTagging) continue;

                    AddTerms(site, termStore, ts.Id, ts.Terms);
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException) { OfficeDropdown.Items.Add("ERROR: Check your Org Term Store Name"); }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { OfficeDropdown.Items.Add("ERROR: Check your Org Term Store Name"); }
        }
    }

    private void AddTerms(SPSite site, TermStore termStore, Guid tsId, TermCollection coll)
    {
        foreach (var t in coll)
        {
            if (t.IsAvailableForTagging)
            {
                var wssIds = TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm(site, termStore.Id, tsId, t.Id, true, 1000);

                if (wssIds.Length != 0)
                {
                    var id = wssIds[0];
                    var validatedString = string.Format("{0};#{1}{2}{3}", id, t.Name, TaxonomyField.TaxonomyGuidLabelDelimiter, t.Id);
                    OfficeDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem(t.Name, validatedString));
                }
                else
                {
                    int id = -1;
                    var value = new TaxonomyFieldValue(SPContext.Current.Web.AvailableFields[new Guid("{a64c1f69-c0d6-421a-8c8a-9ef8f459d7a2}")]);
                    value.TermGuid = t.Id.ToString();

                    var dummy = value.ValidatedString;
                    if (dummy != null)
                        id = value.WssId;

                    var validatedString = string.Format("{0};#{1}{2}{3}", id, t.Name, TaxonomyField.TaxonomyGuidLabelDelimiter, t.Id);
                    OfficeDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem(t.Name, validatedString));
                }
            }
            AddTerms(site, termStore, tsId, t.Terms);
        }
    }
```

### UPDATE:

The bug was in the `TaxonomyField`.  I was accessing terms cross site collection and the IDs hadn't been generated.  Also look out for `TermStore` IDs not being the same cross site collection (and know where you are calling from and where you are calling to!)

Comment: I don't know about SP aspects, but I would suggest that you try narrowing down the code that's failing further to perhaps the line in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions.

1. Pull up `ULS` Log Viewer and study the logs, if you hit the page and get that error, it should be logged there.
2. Check the application event logs on the web front-end server(s).
3. Have you also tried attaching to the `W3P.exe` process and debug the solution? (Assuming it's not the production environment of course).

Comment: The error doesn't get logged into ULS because it is IIS that is crashing. I don't think the process gets far enough along to get to the point that ULS can capture any data. The application event logs say the same thing as what I posted. I'll copy the exact error when I get to work tomorrow. I have attached to the w3wp.exe process, but the actual exception doesn't occur in managed code, so I don't have any of the symbols to track down what happened. I wish I did!